# contextmenu in datagrid with title window

Tags: apache-flex, contextmenu

I want to add a context menu with a datagrid which is in a title window, after adding it nothing happens.

```
[Bindable]      
public var cm:ContextMenu;

private function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{        
 var cmi:ContextMenuItem = new ContextMenuItem("View item...", true);   
 cmi.addEventListener(ContextMenuEvent.MENU_ITEM_SELECT,
                                           ontextMenuItem_menuItemSelect);    
 cm = new ContextMenu();                    
 cm.hideBuiltInItems(); 
 cm.customItems = [cmi];
}
```

I am calling init function on `creationComplete` event of title window.

Please help!!

Comment: when adding code, select it and press `Ctrl + K`. Also, tidy and neat code will get you better answers.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this issue as well. To get it working for my project, I had to explicitly set both of these on the TitleWindow:

```
// "this" being the TitleWindow. Doing this during creation complete event.
this.mouseEnabled = true;
this.skin.mouseEnabled = true;
```